# Regular expression to remove any currency symbol from a string?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to remove any currency symbol from a string value.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string pattern = @"(\p{Sc})?";
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            decimal x = 60.00M;
            txtPrice.Text = x.ToString("c");
        }

        private void btnPrice_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
            string x = rgx.Replace(txtPrice.Text, "");
            txtPrice.Text = x;
        }
    }
}
// The example displays the following output:
// txtPrice.Text = "60.00";
```

This works, but it won't remove currency symbols in Arabic. I don't know why.

The following is a sample Arabic string with a currency symbol.

```
txtPrice.Text = "ج.م.‏ 60.00";
```

Comment: Have you tried using `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol` in your expression?

Comment: @mootinator, did you see word 'any'? You solution will replace only 'current' currency symbol

Comment: @taras.roshko Do you make a habit of making snide remarks 13 months after a comment?  There was obviously a reason that was a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 10):

Don't match the symbol - make an expression that matches the number.

Try something like this:

```
 ([\d,.]+)
```

There are just too many currency symbols to account for. It's better to only capture the data you want. The preceding expression will capture just the numeric data and any place separators.

Use the expression like this:

```
var regex = new Regex(@"([\d,.]+)");

var match = regex.Match(txtPrice.Text);

if (match.Success)
{
    txtPrice.Text = match.Groups[1].Value;
}
```

Comment: Please see my sample code - you won't want to use Regex.Replace with this expression.

Comment: private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            decimal x = 60.00M;
            txtPrice.Text = x.ToString("c");
        }
        private void btnPrice_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string pattern = @"([\d,.]+)";
            Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern);
            string x = rgx.Replace(txtPrice.Text, "");
            txtPrice.Text = x;
        }

Comment: @ramy - You are still using Regex.Replace - please try the sample C# code in my answer that used Regex.Match.

Comment: as ramy has mentioned it the output is only dot.. (my input is $10.50)

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Andrew Hare is almost correct, you can always match digit using \d.*, it will match any digit to your text in question.