# C# - can I parse back text that have already formatted to currency?

Tags: c#, string, parsing, currency, cultureinfo

this is function to format text that contains numbers only into $ currency

```
private String GLOBALIZE_TEXT(String originalText)
{
    decimal parsed;
    CultureInfo myCultureInfo;
    string formattedText = "";

    //use try catch to prevent larger inputs
    try
    {
        parsed = decimal.Parse(originalText, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        myCultureInfo = new CultureInfo("$");
        formattedText = string.Format(myCultureInfo, "{0:c}", parsed);
    }
    catch (Exception ignorethis)
    {
    }
    return formattedText;
}
```

now in usage:

```
String myString = "3821";
myString = GLOBALIZE_TEXT(myString);
//now my String becomes "$3,821.00"
```

question is, can I parse back that "$3,821.00" to "3821" again?
I need to parse it back so I can use it as an integer where "3821" can be converted by `Convert.ToInt32("3821")`.
or maybe that parsed String can also be converted directly to string?

Please let me know your opinion.

Comment: Rather than wrap an exception handler around Parse, you might find it easier to use TryParse:   Decimal.TryParse("$1.00", Globalization.NumberStyles.Currency,

Comment: `MessageBox.Show(int.Parse("$3,821.00", NumberStyles.Currency).ToString());`

Comment: @spajce your code works only when my CultureInfo are "en-US" which is $. but if I put others like "id-ID" which is Indonesian Rp, it won't parse back

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
double.Parse(myString, NumberStyles.Currency);
```

More information on the `NumberStyles` enum can be found [on MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles.aspx) and more information on this specific `double.Parse` method can be found [on MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7yd1h1be.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's best to ask why you need to do this? You should always try and store a value in it's native format. If you need to do it from a captured or imported string then I would go the route of using a regular expression to remove it.

[Regular expression to remove any currency symbol from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120604/regular-expression-to-remove-any-currency-symbol-from-a-string)

Comment: I agree. However a very nice way to handle currency is the money class. http://csharpmoney.codeplex.com