# Validate number with currency symbol

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a grid with represent currency value including the symbol.

User can edit the field which will be updated on `after_edit` event.

I am trying to validate the user input to accept only valid ones. I cannot use normal regex to validate the number `@"^\d{9}$"` as it contains the symbol.

I looked at this question about [Regular expression to remove any currency symbol from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4120604/regular-expression-to-remove-any-currency-symbol-from-a-string) but didn't help.

if the input is "$2ss50.00" it matches and return 2.

Is there anyway that I can do the update if only input like `$250.00`, `£24.50` etc... as the grid value is set using `value.ToString("c2",culture);`

Comment: I think this is too broad as there are so many formats for currencies.

Comment: I don't think so that it will match 2 in `$2ss50.00` as per your regex pattern. since you have used `$` as end of line.

Comment: Do you expect to cope with `1234€` as well as `€1234`? What about `$1.234,45` versus `$1,234.45`?

Comment: @DavidG: there will be no values with thousand separator. if always be in the formats I put in the question

Comment: @huMptyduMpty So only `£` and `$` prefixes?

Comment: @DavidG: No sorry I am not been very clear. Can be any currency, and it may not be always as prefixes. Because the grid value is set `value.ToString("c2",culture)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know the culture, this can be done in C# like this:

```
float value;
var culture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GB");
bool isValidCurrency = float.TryParse(str, NumberStyles.Currency, culture, out value);
```

Comment: oh, been using `decimal.TryParse(grdPayments.Rows[row][_colAmount].ToString(), NumberStyles.Currency, _culture.NumberFormat, out paymentAmount);` all the time and didn't realize I can put `if` condition around that :)

Answer (score 3):

**`\p{Sc}` matches a character from the Unicode category “currency symbol” (any currency sign) in .NET as well as Perl, PCRE, Ruby and Java.**

Use this:

```
^\p{Sc}?[0-9]+\.[0-9]{2}$
```

If the decimals are optional, make it:

```
^\p{Sc}?[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]{2})?$
```

**Explanation**

- The `^` anchor asserts that we are at the beginning of the string
- `\p{Sc}?` matches an optional currency symbol.
- `[0-9]+` matches one or more ASCII digits
- `\.` matches the decimal point
- `[0-9]{2}` matches the decimals
- The `$` anchor asserts that we are at the end of the string

Comment: After a bit of research, used `\p{Sc}` for the currency symbol.